# Read Content from Files which are inside Zip file using Scala/pysprak and also on Databricks and file stored on ADLS

Tags: scala, zip, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, pyspark

I have Zip file of 1.3GB and inside it a txt file with comma separated format which is of 6GB. This zip folder is on Azure Data Lake Storage and using service principle, its mounted on DBFS Databricks file system.
When using normal python code to extract the 6GB file, I get the 1.98GB as extracted file.

Please suggest a way to read the txt file directly and store it as spark Dataframe.

I have tried using python code but directly reading from python gives error -  `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 371`, saw 3
this was also fixed using the `UTF-16-LE` coding but after that got error - `ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) on Databricks while trying to display the df.head().`

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

zfolder = zipfile.ZipFile('dbfszipath') 
zdf = pd.read_csv(zfolder.open('6GBtextfile.txt'),error_bad_lines=False,encoding='UTF-16-LE')
zdf.head()
```

Extract code -

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

zfolder = zipfile.ZipFile('/dbfszippath')
zfolder.extract(dbfsexrtactpath)
```

The dataframe should contain all the data when directly read through the zip folder and also it should display some data and should not hang the Databricks Cluster. Need options in Scala or Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused comes from the memory setting that Databricks and spark have. You will have to increase the size allowance to avoid this error.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf=SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
```

In this case, the allotted memory is 4GB so change it as needed.

Another solution would be the following:

```
import zipfile
import io

def zip_extract(x):
    in_memory_data = io.BytesIO(x[1])
    file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")
    files = [i for i in file_obj.namelist()]
    return dict(zip(files, [file_obj.open(file).read() for file in files]))


zips = sc.binaryFiles("somerandom.zip")
files_data = zips.map(zip_extract)
```

Let me know if this works or what the error is in this case.

[[Source]](https://gist.github.com/vedantja/bd74d0ba7c350dd348af1f92eadd0e76)

Comment: Still getting the error - OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB

Comment: The last sentence of my answer said to "Change it as needed" so change it to something above the memory of the file.

Comment: Ok why are you reading it into a pandas dataframe and not into a spark dataframe?  did you try using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) ? I have also updated my initial post with another possible solution.